# What does adding a scale in the action means?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, lagrangian-formalism, physical-constants, cosmological-constant

I was reading the paper [Analytic topological hairy dyonic black holes and thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02514), where in page two in the second paragraph, the authors write:

> "One way of ensuring regular scalar field at the horizon, thereby evading the no-hair theorem, is by introducing a new scale in the gravitational sector, i.e. via a cosmological constant."

Why the cosmological constant is a scale? In my very little experience a scale is a number, for example if we have a lagrangian $L$ and we scale it by a factor of $a$ such as $aL$, then the Euler Lagrange equations remain the same.

This situation also happens in [de Sitter black hole with a conformally coupled scalar field in four dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205319), where a cosmological constant is introduced. In this case however, there is a potential added for the scalar field $V(\phi) = \alpha \phi^4$ where $\alpha$ is a dimensionless constant. However, the solution exists only for $\alpha =-2\pi G\Lambda/9$, so the paramteter $\alpha$ is related to the cosmological constant. Why can't we have a solution for arbitrary $\alpha$ or even no potential? Does the potential also introduce a scale through $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: a scale is a dimensionful constant. The Einstein-Hilbert action has a dimensionful constant, namely Newton's constant $G_N$. The cosmological constant $\Lambda$ is also dimensionful Since $\Lambda$ is independent of $G_N$ (as far as we know) it represents a *new* scale relative to the Einstein-Hilbert case without a cosmological constant.

What you describe here is not a scale but rather a form of scale invariance:

> In my very little experience a scale is a number, for example if we have a lagrangian  and we scale it by a factor of  such as , then the Euler Lagrange equations remain the same.

The slightly longer answer for why we refer to dimensionful coupling constants as *scales* comes from [Wilsonian effective field theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701053) (see also [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4133) for a discussion of the cosmological constant problem from an effective field theory point of view). Briefly, we think of theories of physics (especially theories that are not perturbatively renormalizable, such as GR) as *effective field theories* which are only valid for describing processes with characteristic energies $E$ below some cutoff scale $M$. Such an effective Lagrangian is expressed as a Taylor series of more and more complicated terms (also known as operators), each with increasingly higher powers of derivatives and fields, suppressed by the dimensionful scale $M$. Since it does not involve any derivatives and has contributions from very lower powers of the fields, the cosmological constant comes to dominate the Einstein-Hilbert term at very long distances (by the uncertainty principle this also means at very low energies); as Wilson effective field theorists we say the cosmological constant is a *relevant* operator because it is important at low energies. The word "scale" reminds us that the physics of a given process will depend on whether the energy of that process is larger, smaller, or approximately the same as the scale in question.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Could you please also comment on the de Sitter black hole case and the potential? Since $\alpha$ is dimensionless i expect that the potential does not add a scale in the action. But it seems that the potential cancels/counterbalances the scale added by the cosmological constant, since i checked that a solution for $\alpha=0$ cannot be found.

Comment: @ApolloRa You are right, I wouldn't call $\alpha$ a scale. But I would say that if you have a dimensionless coupling that needs to take a precise value, then the theory is pretty finely-tuned. The value of $\alpha$ is being carefully chosen to cancel some other terms in the equations of motion... certainly logically possible, but if this choice of $\alpha$ can't be justified by some deep physical principle like a symmetry, my philosophical inclination is to say this choice is perhaps interesting as a mathematical curiosity but unlikely to be physically relevant. Sorry for the negativity.